# Ansible reading Jenkins boolean parameter

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have boolean parameter input from Jenkins. My Ansible then reads this boolean as 'when' condition to execute the tasks. However, this boolean parameter seems not working properly. My playbook looks like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  var: 
    my_boolean: {{lookup('env','boolean_parameter1')}}

- name: print msg1
  debug:
    msg: "msg1 is {{lookup('env','boolean_parameter1')}}."

- name: print msg2
  debug:
    msg: "msg2 is {{my_boolean}}."

- name: execute tasks if my_boolean is 'true'
  shell: ls -l
  when:
    - "{{my_boolean}}"=="true"
```

### Output:

```
msg1 is true.
msg2 is  .
<<<<execution of tasks skipped>>>>
```

Why does msg2 output my_boolean as blank? Should this be 'true' as well?

Answer (score 1):

In your play, the comparison in `when:` is matching the string `"true"`. Whereas the variable `my_boolean` is a boolean, so it doesn't match and skips the task. And in the `debug:` task it is the other way around - the message is trying to display Boolean `true`, and so it is blank.

The below tasks should do the job:

```yaml
# Here we need the string equivalent of boolean, i.e. the text 'true'
- name: print msg2
  debug:
    msg: "msg2 is {{ my_boolean | string }}."

# But here we need to compare the boolean value
- name: execute tasks if my_boolean is 'true'
  shell: ls -l
  when: my_boolean
```

It is worth noting that as of Ansible 2.10 onwards referencing [bare variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#conditional-bare-vars) in `when:` conditionals will be deprecated. It would be a good idea to use: `when: my_boolean | bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `my_boolean` to bool during initialization. This allows to just check if value of `my_boolean` is True.

Playing with your code, the following worked for me:

```
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  vars:
    my_boolean: "{{lookup('env','boolean_parameter1')|bool}}"
  tasks:
    - name: print msg1
      debug:
        msg: "msg1 is {{lookup('env','boolean_parameter1')}}."

    - name: print msg2
      debug:
        msg: "msg2 is {{my_boolean}}."

    - name: execute tasks if my_boolean is 'true'
      shell: ls -l
      when:
        - my_boolean
```

Inventory:

```
[hosts]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```